# Flipping Image horizontally C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

I got a problem with the flipping because only right part is shown, rest of picture is only grey.

```
![Lena FLipped][1]    

Image *im2 = new Image();
im2->CloneImage(image);

unsigned int sizeX = im2->GetSizeX();
unsigned int sizeY = im2->GetSizeY();

for(int x = 0; x < sizeX/2;x++){
   for(int y = 0;y < sizeY;y++ ){

       Image::PixelType pix = im2->GetPixel(x,y);
       im2->SetPixel(x,y,sizeX-x-1);
       im2->SetPixel(sizeX-x-1,y,pix);
   }
}
ImageIO::Write( "flip.pgm", im2 );
```

Comment: im2->SetPixel(x,y,sizeX-x-1);  appears to be causing the problem, it should be set with pixel value of (sizeX-x-1, y)

Answer (score 1):

```
im2->SetPixel(x,y,sizeX-x-1);
```

is wrong, you need to set the colour instead:

```
Image::PixelType pix1 = im2->GetPixel(x,y);
Image::PixelType pix2 = im2->GetPixel(sizeX-x-1,y);
im2->SetPixel(x,y,pix2);
im2->SetPixel(sizeX-x-1,y,pix1);
```

Comment: well, strictly speaking not the colour but the pixel value. anyway your code supplies an X coordinate as 3rd argument to SetPixel, which seems to be wrong: SetPixel wants PixelType as third argument (and therefore pixel value and not a coordinate).

Comment: we get this part from our professor. it works but only half of the image is flipped

Comment: @user: professors make mistakes sometimes, too. :) (I know, I was a lecturer myself many years ago.) just try my code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a full exchange of the two pixels, rather than just overwriting the value -- the grey is coming from this line:

```
im2->SetPixel(x,y,sizeX-x-1);
```

Where you are supplying two x coordinates, and no pixel value. Corrected loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < sizeX/2;x++){
   for(int y = 0;y < sizeY;y++ ){

       Image::PixelType pix = im2->GetPixel(x,y);
       im2->SetPixel(x,y,im2->GetPixel(sizeX-x-1,y));
       im2->SetPixel(sizeX-x-1,y,pix);
   }
}
```

Comment: @mots_g: Cheers, I realised halfway through what was happening and forgot to alter the first bit.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in those lines:

```
   Image::PixelType pix = im2->GetPixel(x,y);
   im2->SetPixel(x,y,sizeX-x-1);
   im2->SetPixel(sizeX-x-1,y,pix);
```

You should memorize both pixel values and then swap them. What is the idea in setting a pixel to `sizeX - x - 1`?